# pandas: check membership in array of lists, avoid looping through columns

Tags: python, pandas

What is the best way to accomplish the following task?

In the following DataFrame,

```
df = DataFrame({'a':[20,21,99], 'b':[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,99],[1,2]], 'c':['x','y','z']})
```

I want to check which elements in column df['a'] are contained in some list in column df['b']. In case there is a match I want the corresponding element in column df['c'], and if no match is found a 0.

So in my example I would like to get a Series:

```
[0,0,'y'].
```

Since 99 is the only element in column df['a'] contained in a list from column df['b'], and that list corresponds to element 'y' in column df['c']

---

I tried:

```
def match(item):
    for ind, row in A.iterrows():
        if item in row.b:
            return row.c
    return False

df['a'].apply(match)
```

But is quite slow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is an example of why you never want a column of lists in a Pandas DataFrame. Accessing the values in the lists force you to use Python loops with no opportunity to really take advantage of Pandas.

Ideally, I think you would be best off altering the way you are constructing `df` so that you do not store the values in `b` as lists. The appropriate data structure to use depends on how you intend to use the data.

For the particular purpose you describe in the question, a `dict` would be useful.

To construct the dict given the current `df`, you could do this:

```
In [69]: dct = {key:row['c'] for i, row in df[['b', 'c']].iterrows() for key in row['b']}

In [70]: df['a'].map(dct).fillna(0)
Out[70]: 
0    0
1    0
2    y
Name: a, dtype: object
```